# sphinx4 raw Lattice demo

Tags: java, speech, jsapi, sphinx4

I have just one simple question about sphinx raw lattice demo (with all of the other Java files that go with it).

Does the program scan the audio file and print out what it thinks the audio file is saying? If not, then why does it need to load an audio file to the Java application?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the program scan the audio file and print out what it thinks the audio file is saying?

Yes